# RadComboBox CheckedItems is always zero for databound items only

Tags: .net, telerik, radcombobox

I have this setup in my code:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox
    id="testBox"
    runat="server"
    AppendDataBoundItems="true"
    DataSourceID="test"
    DataTextField="LabID"
    CheckBoxes="true">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="1" Value="1" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="2" Value="2" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="3" Value="3" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
<telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClick="btnTest_Click" Text="Filter" />
```

Using this `RadComboBox` and `RadButton`, I can select the items 1, 2, and 3 just fine.  However, when I try to select the items from the `DataSource`, the `CheckedItems` property is always equal to zero.

```
public void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FilterByComboBox(testBox);
}

private void FilterByComboBox(RadComboBox box)
{
    var selectedItems = box.CheckedItems;
    //If I select items from the datasource, this will be zero.
}
```

Has anyone seen this behavior?  How can I get the databound items to behave properly?

Thanks in advance!